# $V$ is locally closed subscheme (i.e. a closed subscheme of an open subscheme of $X$) do not implies that it's the open subscheme of closed subscheme

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, schemes

I was reading Professor Vakil's FOAG, and in exercise 9.2B there is a statement that :

If $V$ is an open subscheme of a closed subscheme will implies that $V$ is a closed subscheme of an open subscheme. But the converse does not hold. (Professor Vakil's provides an counterexample on [Stacks Project](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01QW))

---

Therefore the following proof is a fake proof for the converse direction:

Let $V$ be a closed subscheme of some open subscheme $U$, then as a closed subset, it's the intersection of $U$ with some closed subset $K$ in $X$ therefore $V = K\cap U$ then $V$ is open subscheme of $K$ which is again a closed subscheme of $X$.

Where does the proof above go wrong?

Comment: As sets of points that is so. But what about the scheme structure?

Comment: Thank you @Zhen Lin .Do you mean the closed subset $K$ may not have a scheme structure on it? this is not possible what you mean since I see in some place closed subset always has (possibly not unique) scheme structure.  Or you may possible means that closed subscheme structure on $K$ may not give the same scheme strucutre on $V$ as the original one?

Comment: There will be at least one closed subscheme structure on it. But it can also happen that all of the closed subscheme structures are different from what you started with. That is the point of the counterexample!

Comment: got it thank you Zhen Lin